# Load a map with geoxml using parseKmlString() and parse()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geoxml3

**OLD POST**

> How can I use `parse` and `parseKmlString` together?? I need show a
>   map loading one KML file (I use `parse(<kml_file>)`) and two XML
>   string (I use `parseKmlString(<xml_string>)`). How I use `useTheData`
>   in `afterParse` property?? I don't know how I must manage this case.
>   Can I use only one `geoxml = new geoxml.parser()` for three "layers"?
>   How would I manage `doc` parameter in `userTheData` to get a "KML file
>   layer" or "XML string layer"?
>
> PD: Sorry for my english. It's very difficult to explain what I need.

**MODIFIED POST**

I draw a map dinamically with ASP. If I get 3 layers, a write 3 object (geoxml_1, geoxml_2 and geoxml_3). It would be only one object, and show and hidden layer 1 or layer2.... That is my problem. Really it works, but it isn't fine code. When I load de map, it show all layers, and in a few seconds, only show the first layer and hidden the others. I would like whow only the first layer, an when I click the others layers in my buttons inside the map, it would show and hide de layers. This is my code (sorry, its too large):

```
function muestraCapasMapa(){
    var objCapa = document.getElementById("capas_mapa");
    var objFlecha = document.getElementById("flecha");
    if (objCapa.className=="ocultar"){
        objCapa.className = "";
        objFlecha.className = "plegar";
    }else{
        objCapa.className = "ocultar";
        objFlecha.className = "";
    }
}

var infoWindow;
var map_1 = null;
var geoXml_1;
var bounds_1;
var blnKmlServicio_1;
var geoXml_2;
var bounds_2;
var blnKmlServicio_2;
var geoXml_3;
var bounds_3;
var blnKmlServicio_3;
var boundsTotal;
var SDLLayer;
var btnPulsado;

function useTheData_1(doc){
    var geoXmlDoc = doc[0];                
    for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {


    var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
        var bounds_parciales;

        if (placemark.polyline) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.polyline.bounds;

                bounds_1.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.polygon){
            bounds_parciales = placemark.polygon.bounds;

                bounds_1.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.marker) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.marker.getPosition();

                bounds_1.extend(bounds_parciales);

        }

    }   // END FOR     
}   //END FUNCTION

function useTheData_2(doc){
    var geoXmlDoc = doc[0];                
    for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {


    var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
        var bounds_parciales;

        if (placemark.polyline) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.polyline.bounds;

                bounds_2.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.polygon){
            bounds_parciales = placemark.polygon.bounds;

                bounds_2.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.marker) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.marker.getPosition();

                bounds_2.extend(bounds_parciales);

        }

    }   // END FOR     
}   //END FUNCTION

function useTheData_3(doc){
    var geoXmlDoc = doc[0];                
    for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {


    var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
        var bounds_parciales;

        if (placemark.polyline) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.polyline.bounds;

                bounds_3.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.polygon){
            bounds_parciales = placemark.polygon.bounds;

                bounds_3.union(bounds_parciales);

        }

        if (placemark.marker) {

        bounds_parciales = placemark.marker.getPosition();

                bounds_3.extend(bounds_parciales);

        }

    }   // END FOR     
}   //END FUNCTION


function initialize_1() {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infoWindows = [];

    function closeAllInfoWindows(infoW) {
        for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
            if (infoWindows[i] != infoW){
                infoWindows[i].close();
            }
        }
    }   

    boundsTotal = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds_1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds_2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds_3 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    //Declaramos las variables que vamos a user
    var lat_1 = null;
    var lng_1 = null;

    var lngLatitud;
    var lngLongitud;
    var zoom;
    zoom=9;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.82907321372808, -4.46044921875);

    //Definimos algunas opciones del mapa a crear
    var myOptions = {
        center: latLng, //centro del mapa
        zoom: zoom,
        scrollwheel: false,
        styles: [{"featureType": "water","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{    "visibility": "on"}, {    "color": "#A6DBD8"}]}, {"featureType": "landscape","elementType": "geometry.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#DEDDAC"}]}, {"featureType": "poi","elementType": "geometry.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#769E72"}]}, {"featureType": "poi","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#7B8758"}]}, {"featureType": "poi","elementType": "labels.text.stroke","stylers": [{"color": "#EBF4A4"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}, {"color": "#CFD978"}]}, {"featureType": "road","elementType": "geometry.fill","stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]}, {"featureType": "road","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#5B5B3F"}]}, {"featureType": "road","elementType": "labels.text.stroke","stylers": [{"color": "#ABCE83"}]}, {"featureType": "road","elementType": "labels.icon","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "road.local","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#A4C67D"}]}, {"featureType": "road.arterial","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#CFCBB4"}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#B6B6B6"}]}, {"featureType": "transit","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "administrative","elementType": "geometry.stroke","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}, {"color": "#87ae79"}]}, {"featureType": "administrative","elementType": "geometry.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#7f2200"}, {"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "administrative","elementType": "labels.text.stroke","stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"}, {"visibility": "on"}, {"weight": 4.1}]}, {"featureType": "administrative","elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#495421"}]}, {"featureType": "administrative.neighborhood","elementType": "labels","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}],
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //tipo de mapa, carretera, híbrido,etc
    }; // Fin my options

    //creamos el mapa con las opciones anteriores y le pasamos el elemento div
    map_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_1"), myOptions);
    geoXml_1 = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map_1,
        infoWindowOptions: {maxWidth:350},
        singleInfoWindow: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        afterParse: parseoTerminado_1,
        zoom: false
    });                    

    function parseoTerminado_1(doc){ 
        useTheData_1(doc);                   
        setTimeout(function() {
            compruebaCapas_1();
            setTimeout(function() {
                chequearCapas();
            }, 0) 
            /*chequeo burbujas*/                            


                $.each(geoXml_1.docs[0].gpolylines, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_1.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow);                                                                 
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_1.docs[0].gpolylines[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_1.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow); 
                    });
                });

                $.each(geoXml_1.docs[0].markers, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_1.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow);                                     
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_1.docs[0].markers[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_1.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow); 
                    });                                    
                });
                //console.log(".>" + infoWindows);

            /***************/
        }, 500) 
    }                   
    blnKmlServicio_1 = true;
    geoXml_1.parse('<URL_GET_KML>');

    geoXml_2 = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map_1,
        infoWindowOptions: {maxWidth:350},

            singleInfoWindow: true,

            suppressInfoWindows: false,

        afterParse: parseoTerminado_2,
        zoom: false
    });                    

    function parseoTerminado_2(doc){ 
        useTheData_2(doc);                   
        setTimeout(function() {
            compruebaCapas_2();
            setTimeout(function() {
                chequearCapas();
            }, 0) 
            /*chequeo burbujas*/                            


                $.each(geoXml_2.docs[0].gpolylines, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_2.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow);                                                                 
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_2.docs[0].gpolylines[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_2.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow); 
                    });
                });

                $.each(geoXml_2.docs[0].markers, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_2.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow);                                     
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_2.docs[0].markers[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_2.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow); 
                    });                                    
                });
                //console.log(".>" + infoWindows);

            /***************/
        }, 500) 
    }                

    blnKmlServicio_2 = false;
    geoXml_2.parseKmlString("<KML_STRING>");

    geoXml_3 = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map_1,
        infoWindowOptions: {maxWidth:350},

            singleInfoWindow: true,

            suppressInfoWindows: false,

        afterParse: parseoTerminado_3,
        zoom: false
    });                    

    function parseoTerminado_3(doc){ 
        useTheData_3(doc);                   
        setTimeout(function() {
            compruebaCapas_3();
            setTimeout(function() {
                chequearCapas();
            }, 0) 
            /*chequeo burbujas*/                            


                $.each(geoXml_3.docs[0].gpolylines, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_3.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow);                                                                 
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_3.docs[0].gpolylines[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_3.docs[0].gpolylines[index].infoWindow); 
                    });
                });

                $.each(geoXml_3.docs[0].markers, function(index) {                           
                    infoWindows.push(geoXml_3.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow);                                     
                    google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml_3.docs[0].markers[index], 'click', function() {
                        closeAllInfoWindows(geoXml_3.docs[0].markers[index].infoWindow); 
                    });                                    
                });
                //console.log(".>" + infoWindows);

            /***************/
        }, 500) 
    }                

    blnKmlServicio_3 = false;
    geoXml_3.parseKmlString("<KML_STRING>");

    CrearBotones(map_1);

    function compruebaCapas_1(n){
        if (!blnKmlServicio_1){
            if (document.getElementById("Capa_1")){
                if (document.getElementById("Capa_1").checked){
                    geoXml_1.showDocument();
                    boundsTotal.union(bounds_1);
                }else{
                    geoXml_1.hideDocument();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function compruebaCapas_2(n){
        if (!blnKmlServicio_2){
            if (document.getElementById("Capa_2")){
                if (document.getElementById("Capa_2").checked){
                    geoXml_2.showDocument();
                    boundsTotal.union(bounds_2);
                }else{
                    geoXml_2.hideDocument();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function compruebaCapas_3(n){
        if (!blnKmlServicio_3){
            if (document.getElementById("Capa_3")){
                if (document.getElementById("Capa_3").checked){
                    geoXml_3.showDocument();
                    boundsTotal.union(bounds_3);
                }else{
                    geoXml_3.hideDocument();
                }
            }
        }
    }


        $("a#inline").fancybox({
            // RESIZE MAP WHEN TU CLICK A BUTTON
        });

}   //END initialize 


function CrearBotones(map) {
    // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
    // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
    // from the edge of the map
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

    // Creamos el DIV que contendrá al botón y asignamos los estilos
    var controlUI_1 = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI_1.id = 'btnZoom';
    controlUI_1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI_1.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI_1.style.borderWidth = '1px 1px 0px 1px';
    controlUI_1.style.borderColor = 'rgb(178, 177, 138)';
    controlUI_1.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    controlUI_1.style.boxShadow = '0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
    controlUI_1.style.marginTop = '0px';
    controlUI_1.style.marginRight = '5px';
    controlUI_1.style.marginBottom = '5px';
    controlUI_1.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlUI_1.style.paddingBottom = '0px';
    controlUI_1.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlUI_1.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI_1.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI_1.style.display = 'block';
    controlUI_1.title = 'Haz click aquí para ampliar el mapa a pantalla completa';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI_1);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlUI_1);

    // Creamos el DIV interno que tendrá la etiqueta y HTML del botón
    var controlText_1 = document.createElement('div');
    controlText_1.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText_1.style.fontSize = '11px';
    controlText_1.style.lineHeight = '14.5px';
    controlText_1.style.paddingTop = '2px';
    controlText_1.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlText_1.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlText_1.innerHTML = '<a id="inline" href="#divMapaGlobal" class="icon icon-fullscreen" style="font-size:11px;text-decoration:none;"></a>';                                        
    controlUI_1.appendChild(controlText_1);
    controlDiv.index=1;

    // Creamos el DIV que contendrá al botón y asignamos los estilos
    var controlUI_2 = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI_2.id = 'btnOrtofotos';
    controlUI_2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI_2.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI_2.style.borderWidth = '1px 1px 0px 1px';
    controlUI_2.style.borderColor = 'rgb(178, 177, 138)';
    controlUI_2.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    controlUI_2.style.boxShadow = '0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
    controlUI_2.style.marginTop = '5px';
    controlUI_2.style.marginRight = '5px';
    controlUI_2.style.marginBottom = '0px';
    controlUI_2.style.marginLeft = '5px';
    controlUI_2.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlUI_2.style.paddingBottom = '0px';
    controlUI_2.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlUI_2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI_2.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI_2.style.display = 'block';
    controlUI_2.title = 'Haz click aquí para ver el mapa de ortofotos';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI_2);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlUI_2);

    // Creamos el DIV interno que tendrá la etiqueta y HTML del botón
    var controlText_2 = document.createElement('div');
    controlText_2.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText_2.style.fontSize = '11px';
    controlText_2.style.lineHeight = '14.5px';
    controlText_2.style.paddingTop = '2px';
    controlText_2.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlText_2.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlText_2.innerHTML = 'Ortofoto';                                       
    controlUI_2.appendChild(controlText_2);
    controlDiv.index=2;

    //En caso de que sea el botón de Ortofotos, lanzamos el evento para mostrar el mapa
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI_2, 'click', function() {
        MuestraMapaOrtofotos();
    });

    // Creamos el DIV que contendrá al botón y asignamos los estilos
    var controlUI_3 = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI_3.id = 'btnCapas';
    controlUI_3.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI_3.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI_3.style.borderWidth = '1px 1px 0px 1px';
    controlUI_3.style.borderColor = 'rgb(178, 177, 138)';
    controlUI_3.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    controlUI_3.style.boxShadow = '0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
    controlUI_3.style.marginTop = '5px';
    controlUI_3.style.marginRight = '5px';
    controlUI_3.style.marginBottom = '0px';
    controlUI_3.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlUI_3.style.paddingBottom = '0px';
    controlUI_3.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlUI_3.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI_3.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI_3.style.display = 'block';
    controlUI_3.title = 'Haz click aquí para ver los puntos de interés';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI_3);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlUI_3);

    // Creamos el DIV interno que tendrá la etiqueta y HTML del botón
    var controlText_3 = document.createElement('div');  
    controlText_3.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif'; 
    controlText_3.style.fontSize = '11px';  
    controlText_3.style.lineHeight = '14.5px';  
    controlText_3.style.paddingTop = '2px'; 
    controlText_3.style.paddingLeft = '4px';    
    controlText_3.style.paddingRight = '12px';  
    controlText_3.innerHTML = '<a id="btnCapas" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="muestraCapasMapa();">Más información<span id="flecha"></span></a><div id="capas_mapa" class="ocultar" onload="mostrarCapas();"><div><input type="checkbox" checked id="Capa_1" for="Capa_1" onclick="chequearCapas();" /><label for="Capa_1"  style="background-image:url(<url_ico_layer1>)">Ruta Gran Senda</label></div><div><input type="checkbox"id="Capa_2" for="Capa_2" onclick="chequearCapas();" /><label for="Capa_2"  style="background-image:url(<url_ico_layer2>)">Gran Recorrido</label></div><div><input type="checkbox"id="Capa_3" for="Capa_3" onclick="chequearCapas();" /><label for="Capa_3"  style="background-image:url(<url_ico_layer3>)">Pequeño Recorrido</label></div></div>';                                         
    controlUI_3.appendChild(controlText_3);

    controlDiv.index=3;            
}

function chequearCapas(){
    var vacio = true;
    var boundsCapas = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    geoXml_1.hideDocument();
    if (document.getElementById("Capa_1")){
        if (document.getElementById("Capa_1").checked){
            geoXml_1.showDocument();
            boundsCapas.union(bounds_1);
            vacio = false;
        }
        else{
                geoXml_1.hideDocument();
        }
    }else{
       geoXml_1.showDocument();
    } 

    geoXml_2.hideDocument();
    if (document.getElementById("Capa_2")){
        if (document.getElementById("Capa_2").checked){
            geoXml_2.showDocument();
            boundsCapas.union(bounds_2);
            vacio = false;
        }else{
            geoXml_2.hideDocument();
        }
    }else{
       geoXml_1.showDocument();
    } 

    geoXml_3.hideDocument();
    if (document.getElementById("Capa_3")){
        if (document.getElementById("Capa_3").checked){
            geoXml_3.showDocument();
            boundsCapas.union(bounds_3);
            vacio = false;
        }else{
            geoXml_3.hideDocument();
        }
    }else{
       geoXml_1.showDocument();
    } 

    if (vacio){
        //Manilva: 36.376063, -5.250776
        //Nerja: 36.757568, -3.872232
        //Alameda: 37.208805, -4.659323
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(36.376063),
            parseFloat(-5.250776)
        );
        boundsCapas.extend(point);   //Añadimos puntos

        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(36.757568),
            parseFloat(-3.872232)
        );
        boundsCapas.extend(point);   //Añadimos puntos

        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(36.208805),
            parseFloat(-4.659323)
        );
        boundsCapas.extend(point);   //Añadimos puntos
    }
    if (map_1!=null){
        map_1.fitBounds(boundsCapas);
    }
}
```

PD: You can load the map using `initialize_1()`. It's too heavy, I hope it will for you to explain my problem better.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I think I've found the solution to my problem. Finally I only create one geoXml object. I loaded four layers using `parse(<url>)`:

```
<url_layer>/location.asp
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=1
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=2
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=3"
```

If you checked `geoxml.docs.length` you get 2!! So, if I show or hide the `layer2` o `layer3` could be wrong. The solution has been call to differents urls to get `geoxml.docs.length==4`:

```
<url_layer>/location.asp
<url_layer>/rute1.asp
<url_layer>/rute2.asp
<url_layer>/rute3.asp
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  What does the KML look like?  The general answer is you should be able to use one instance of geoxml3 for as many KML "layers" as you want. [Example with 5 "layers"](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_utah-hunt_linkto.html)

Comment: My code is too heavy...mmmm, ok!! At the moment, I've a map and I show as many buttons as layers. When it loads I only parse (with parse(<kml_file>) and I show the first layer (I don´t want to load the otres layers, because you can see to lad, although I can hide it). If you click in any button, if it s the first time you will load it with parseKmlString(<xml_string>), and if you click it again, it will hide. Now, my problem is that I increase geoxml.docs, but it doesn't hide the correct layer. PUFFFF!! It's to heavy to explain XDD. I'll try to make a jsfiddle to show my problem, ok?

Comment: @geocodezip I review all your examples. It's great, but I don´t find any example using parse() and parseKmlString(). I've make a jsfiddle to show you but I can't load an external url to load "parse(<kml_file>)" :(

Comment: Then post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, including enough samples of KML (and possibly also links to the complete files) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip I edited my post. I hope it's ok! How I could send you a private message?? XDDD

Comment: What does the KML look like?

Comment: I exported to googlemaps that layer. You can see it here: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=ztxVeqlYMaNA.kq12bjfbLTaY

Comment: Can you see 4 buttons (G+, Fb, Tw and "share")? Make click on "share" to download the KML. Do you mean that?

Comment: The map is not public, won't allow the KML to be exported.  Please don't post code in comments, it is hard to read, update your question with any code.

Comment: You are right!! Sorry. Comment deleted and post updated. Certainly, I made the map with public mode for all get the link. I'll check it.

Comment: I've modified the map to public mode. Can you cheack it??

Comment: You're right. Done!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I think I've found the solution to my problem. Finally I only create one geoXml object. I loaded four layers using `parse(<url>)`:

```
<url_layer>/location.asp
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=1
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=2
<url_layer>/rute.asp?tip=3"
```

If you checked `geoxml.docs.length` you get 2!! So, if I show or hide the `layer2` o `layer3` could be wrong. The solution has been call to differents urls to get `geoxml.docs.length==4`:

```
<url_layer>/location.asp
<url_layer>/rute1.asp
<url_layer>/rute2.asp
<url_layer>/rute3.asp
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
               map: map,
               infoWindow: infowindow,
               singleInfoWindow: true
             });
geoXml.parse(filename);
geoXml.parse("TrashDays40.xml");
geoXml.parseKmlString('<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Placemark><name><![CDATA[]]>Polygon</name><description><![CDATA[]]></description><Polygon><extrude>1</extrude><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-93.46008301171878,31.329035778926478,0 -98.30505371484378,31.40065516914794,0 -97.37121582421878,30.106233605369603,0 -92.65808105859378,30.14749530904506,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>');
```

[working example (with 4 files)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_parseKmlString_linktoB0.html?lat=34.430524&lng=-64.261117&zoom=3&type=m&filename=voterdistricts_address.xml&filename2=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/ExternKml.kml)